# The equation of $AB$ is $y= 2x-6$ The equation of $AC$ is $y= -x+12$. Calculate the size of the angle $A$

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image]

I have tried various methods as to answer this question using $\sin$ and $\tan$ but I cannot seem to attach my working out please send me the answers no working out needed as I just want to see where I went wrong 
thank you

Comment: Welcome to the website. For any doubts on how to use mathematical notation please check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Angle bwtween 2 lines from slopes arctan 2 - arctan (-1)

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the dot product of two vectors and the angle between them?

Answer (score 0):

$A+D+E=180°$

Now the slope of $AB$ is the same as $AD$ and it's equal to the tangent of the angle $ADE$. Instead for $AED$ we need to do $180°-AEF$ where the tangent of $AEF$ is the slope of $AE$ that is the same as $AC$.

$A+\arctan(2)+180°-\arctan(-1)=180°$

$A=\arctan(-1)-\arctan(2)$

$A=71,6°$

Comment: I don't get the downvote..

Comment: I upvoted but you don't need a lot of the verbiage.  Just take your second A=  line as obvious; i.e. use the slopes as tan()... then subtract the arctan() 's of the slopes and then usual geometry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all calculate the slope of both these lines by comparing with the formula  of a standard equation of line as :
y= mx +c , c being a constant.
 for line AB you will find 'm1' and for line AC , you can deduce 'm2' such that 'm1' and 'm2' being the respective slopes for the lines AB and AC.
Now after deducing 'm1' and 'm2', find the angle '∆'  between the lines AB and AC as:
tan(∆) = (m1 - m2)/(1 + m1*m2).